# How to avoid losing borders when table td content is too long？

Tags: c#, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I encountered a very tricky problem. In the. Net core project, I used wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML into PDF. However, when the content in td in the page table was too long, the top and bottom borders of the generated PDF file table disappeared. I tried all the solutions but they didn't work. I even thought about whether it was possible to read the PDF file again after it was generated, and then forcefully insert a line at the top and bottom. What am I supposed to do?

[image]

I hope the table border on the new page can display normally. I tried adding various CSS attributes, but none of them worked

Comment: i have long content on td and page-break doesn't work here.
table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot { page-break-inside: avoid !important; }
that's not working to me